# Add a property to a document set

Tags: document-set

I need to add some custom properties to a document set.
Is there an ootb way to do this or inheriting the content type is the only solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what you see as an ootb solution.

A Document Set is a 'special' content type with `ContentType ID="0x0120D520"`, so sort of a Folder content type. To add custom properties (fields) to a document set you can go several ways:

- Add a site/list column through the SharePoint UI as you would do with a regular content type
- Add a SPField in code, e.g. in an event receiver
- Add a SPField in the Document Set content type definition declaratively

If you can do it for a regular content type, you can do it for a document set, since it's 'just a content type'.

If you want your custom fields to be shared to the document types in the document set or shown on the welcome page, have a look at this [Visual How To](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg581064.aspx) for a highly detailed definition.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. Thanks for the answer!